# batch.models.PoolAddParameter with low priority nodes with python

Tags: python, azure

When I'm using batch.models.PoolAddParameter as follow:

```
new_pool = batch.models.PoolAddParameter(
    id=pool_id,
    vm_size=pool_vm_size,
    target_dedicated=pool_node_count,
    target_low_priority=pool_lowprioritynode_count,
    max_tasks_per_node=pool_max_tasks_per_node,
    cloud_service_configuration=batch.models.CloudServiceConfiguration(
        os_family=os_family,
        target_os_version=target_os_version,
    ),
    application_package_references=[batch.models.ApplicationPackageReference(
        application_id=application_id,
        version=application_version,
    )],
    start_task=batch.models.StartTask(
        command_line=wrap_commands_in_shell('windows', task_commands),
        run_elevated=True,
        wait_for_success=True,
        resource_files=resource_files),
    task_scheduling_policy=batch.models.TaskSchedulingPolicy(
        node_fill_type=batch.models.ComputeNodeFillType.spread)
    )
```

i'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target_lowpriority'`

I tried with

target_lowpriority

target_lowpriority_nodes

target_low_priority

target_low_priority_nodes

It works all fine without the target_lowpriority ( and variants) 
I looked in the various azure documentation online, and could not find an example of  batch.models.PoolAddParameter with target_low_priority_nodes.
Can anyone help here ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Scale a pool containing low-priority VMs chapter in [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-low-pri-vms), pool auto-scale formula supports low-priority VMs only supports three variables:
  `targetLowPriorityNodes`,`CurrentLowPriorityNodes` and `PreemptedNodeCount`.

You can see [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/6fcdcc88629a24c5b28a65a479d3e21b93b9ca3d/azure-batch/azure/batch/models/pool_add_parameter.py#L162) of `PoolAddParameter` method , it only supports  `'target_low_priority_nodes': {'key': 'targetLowPriorityNodes', 'type': 'int'}` , **targetLowPriority** can't be found indeed.

So , please use `target_low_priority_nodes` to scale a pool containing low-priority VMs.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks very much for your answer. I might be missing something as , as stated in my original question, I tried `target_low_priority_nodes` already and I get the same error. Also, note that for dedicated nodes,  using `target_dedicated` instead of `target_dedicated_nodes`', actually works.

Comment: Sorry, not sure my last comment was clear. I have tried with `target_low_priority_nodes`    And it does not work better, I get the same error message

Comment: @user3116727 Please use pip freeze to  check your Azure Batch python package version.If the version is too old,syntax problem will occur.